# near indexer does not add anything to the database

Tags: nearprotocol

I've tried to run https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer

No firewall, IP accessable (tested right now).

With empty data, it waits for peers forever.

With data from the run started some days ago

```
./target/release/indexer-explorer --home-dir ../.near/mainnet run  --store-genesis  --stream-while-syncing --allow-missing-relations-in-first-blocks 1000  sync-from-latest
```

It does something

```
Nov 01 18:42:23.293  INFO indexer_for_explorer: AccessKeys from genesis were added/updated successful.
Nov 01 18:42:33.188  INFO stats: # 9820210 Waiting for peers   1/1/40 peers ⬇ 0 B/s ⬆ 0 B/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 0%, Mem: 0 B
Nov 01 18:42:43.190  INFO stats: # 9820210 Downloading headers 68.72% (13074549)   3/3/40 peers ⬇ 149.3kiB/s ⬆ 6.0kiB/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 23%, Mem: 510.7 MiB
Nov 01 18:42:53.192  INFO stats: # 9820210 Downloading headers 68.72% (13074559)   2/2/40 peers ⬇ 299.4kiB/s ⬆ 297.5kiB/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 40%, Mem: 621.3 MiB
Nov 01 18:43:03.194  INFO stats: # 9820210 Downloading headers 68.72% (13074569)   1/1/40 peers ⬇ 150.1kiB/s ⬆ 148.9kiB/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 42%, Mem: 520.7 MiB
Nov 01 18:43:13.196  INFO stats: # 9820210 Downloading headers 68.72% (13074578)   2/2/40 peers ⬇ 150.3kiB/s ⬆ 148.8kiB/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 10%, Mem: 631.6 MiB
Nov 01 18:43:23.198  INFO stats: # 9820210 Downloading headers 68.72% (13074590)   2/1/40 peers ⬇ 294.1kiB/s ⬆ 297.6kiB/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 14%, Mem: 601.5 MiB
Nov 01 18:43:33.200  INFO stats: # 9820210 Downloading headers 68.72% (13074598)   1/1/40 peers ⬇ 149.4kiB/s ⬆ 148.8kiB/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 2%, Mem: 602.9 MiB
Nov 01 18:43:43.203  INFO stats: # 9820210 EPnLgE7iEq9s7yTkos96M3cWymH5avBAPm3qx3NXqR8H -/4  2/2/40 peers ⬇ 150.0kiB/s ⬆ 148.8kiB/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 9%, Mem: 657.0 MiB
Nov 01 18:43:53.209  INFO stats: # 9820210 Downloading headers 68.72% (13074608)   1/1/40 peers ⬇ 150.5kiB/s ⬆ 148.8kiB/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 3%, Mem: 661.0 MiB
Nov 01 18:44:03.212  INFO stats: # 9820210 EPnLgE7iEq9s7yTkos96M3cWymH5avBAPm3qx3NXqR8H -/4  1/1/40 peers ⬇ 148.6kiB/s ⬆ 148.8kiB/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 4%, Mem: 664.8 MiB
Nov 01 18:44:13.213  INFO stats: # 9820210 EPnLgE7iEq9s7yTkos96M3cWymH5avBAPm3qx3NXqR8H -/4  0/0/40 peers ⬇ 0 B/s ⬆ 0 B/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 2%, Mem: 664.8 MiB
Nov 01 18:44:23.215  INFO stats: # 9820210 EPnLgE7iEq9s7yTkos96M3cWymH5avBAPm3qx3NXqR8H -/4  0/0/40 peers ⬇ 0 B/s ⬆ 0 B/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 1%, Mem: 666.8 MiB
Nov 01 18:44:33.217  INFO stats: # 9820210 Downloading headers 68.72% (13074655)   1/1/40 peers ⬇ 150.0kiB/s ⬆ 148.8kiB/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 11%, Mem: 614.7 MiB
Nov 01 18:44:43.219  INFO stats: # 9820210 EPnLgE7iEq9s7yTkos96M3cWymH5avBAPm3qx3NXqR8H -/4  0/0/40 peers ⬇ 0 B/s ⬆ 0 B/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 1%, Mem: 614.9 MiB
Nov 01 18:44:53.224  INFO stats: # 9820210 EPnLgE7iEq9s7yTkos96M3cWymH5avBAPm3qx3NXqR8H -/4  0/0/40 peers ⬇ 0 B/s ⬆ 0 B/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 1%, Mem: 614.9 MiB
Nov 01 18:45:03.227  INFO stats: # 9820210 EPnLgE7iEq9s7yTkos96M3cWymH5avBAPm3qx3NXqR8H -/4  0/0/40 peers ⬇ 0 B/s ⬆ 0 B/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 1%, Mem: 616.4 MiB
Nov 01 18:45:13.232  INFO stats: # 9820210 EPnLgE7iEq9s7yTkos96M3cWymH5avBAPm3qx3NXqR8H -/4  0/0/40 peers ⬇ 0 B/s ⬆ 0 B/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 1%, Mem: 616.4 MiB
```

But nothing get added to database.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your concern about the indexing part (no data in the database) will get resolved once the node reaches “syncing blocks” stage. Currently, your node is still only at “syncing block headers” stage. To speed up this process, start from a backup: https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/node/validator/running-a-node#starting-a-node-from-backup

As to the fact that the node dropped off the p2p network, I have no clues why that could have happened. I recommend you start with running a simple neard node and report any issues there before you get to the Indexer (which is just an extension to nearcore and thus you can use the same home & data folder)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, indexer *requires* full archive mode. Links to 5-epoch are misleading. They are not usable for indexer.

Second (may save lots of time for downloading), indexer requires AVX extension to run. If your CPU does not AVX, don't bother building nearcore. That should be mentioned in docs. nearcore depends on some wasm, wasm requires AVX to run. Indexer will run for some time and fail miserably without AVX.

Comment: FYI, nearcore 1.22.0+ is compilable on M1, so the note about AVX is not applicable anymore

Comment: While indeed archival backup is preferrable, using `--non-strict-mode` can get you running from 5-epoch backup, though part of the data won't be stored (`access_keys` and `account_changes` will be skipped)

Comment: I've wrote (with lots of help from NEAR community) a simple program keeping a list of accounts. That's exactly what I needed, I'll clarify the code and github it.